# Submit 64 bit only app

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

With Apple's new requirement to have a 64 bit build support, apps executable are getting bigger.

After several attempt to reduce the final build size to something < 100mb I was wondering if it was possible to drop 32 bit support and only support 64bit.

Building an app for 64bit only works fine but the submission process seems to prevent such behavior.

[image: arm64 error]

Adding this [non-documented UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3) does not change anything as the error becomes the following[image]

I checked that there is no mention of armv7 or armv7s in my architectures settings

Yet people on the [Unity forum](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/64bit-only-ios-builds.295355/) seems to say that it's possible based on a similar conversation on [Apple's Forum](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1098481#1098481)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 8 (and iOS 9) are supported on 32 bit devices, such as the iPhone4s so you must include armv7 in your builds. You will need to wait for app thining in iOS 9 to reduce your bundle size.

Comment: Seems there is no option for this. Platform state of the Union WWDC 2015 seems to say the same thing.