# How to submit a 64-bit only [downgrade] iOS app update

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, 64-bit, app-store-connect

I'm working in a game made in Unity3D and due to the large size of the binary I'm considering the idea of targeting only 64-bit devices (and thus, avoiding the armv7 and armv7s slices in the fat binary). Bitcode is currently not an option due to 3rd party frameworks (specially Google) so 64-bit targeting is my last resort.

In [Platforms State of the Union](http://asciiwwdc.com/2015/sessions/102) it is said that "So going forward, we will allow you to submit 64-bit only apps to the store, starting with iOS 9 later this year.", which makes me think that it is currently possible.

I've seen some [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30729940/submit-64-bit-only-app) about `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` hacking but without success.

My Xcode version is `Version 7.1.1 (7B1005)`.

Does someone know what are the actual steps to submit a 64-only app?

---

**EDIT:**

Let me make myself clear:

- My app is **currently** available in the App Store for both `armv7` and `arm64` architectures.

  1. Is it possible to submit a `arm64`-only update (downgrade, remove support for `armv7`)?
  2. What happens if an user that has a `armv7` device looks up my app on the App Store? Will the user be allowed to download the previous version of my app (the one that supports both `armv7` and `arm64`)?

---

Thanks

Comment: I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646553/ios-limit-app-to-64-bit-devices-only) question. Have you tried setting the architecture to arm64  only?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to do the following steps in Xcode:

---

1. `Info.plist`  > `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`

   Set to `arm64` only.
2. `Build settings` > `Architectures`

   Set to `arm64` only.
3. `Build settings` > `Valid architectures`

   Set to `arm64` only.

---

You might want to read about this from the official site. Just check out this [link to apples developer page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3) about using keys.

This worked perfectly in [my app for *iOS 9*](http://appstore.com/prismblockadsbeautifythewebadblock). If you try to test run on an *iPhone 5* (for example) it should not work and come up with an error.
When uploading to *iTunes Connect* there is no further thing you need to check. It will appear on every *App Store*, but you will only be able to install it, if your device supports *64 bit*.

---

***EDIT:***

1. Downgrading from **armv7** to only **arm64** has to be possible without
   apple rejecting the app.

   ***Because
   ->***
2. If the user has once bought your app and and your apps' current version doesn't work on that specific device, downloading an older version is no problem*. **Anyway:** New users (have not bought your app yet) wich devices don't support your current apps' version will not be able to buy the app!

   *the same thing as shown [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/195074/how-do-i-install-an-older-version-of-an-app-on-an-iphone) but with 64 bit

Comment: Hi @Devapploper. 1) Could you send me the link to your app so that I can test on my iPhone (arm64) and iPad (armv7s)? 2) Have you previously submitted your app with support for both armv7 and arm64? My app is currently available for both platforms and I don't know if it is possible to 'downgrade' to arm64 only.

Comment: Hi, I could send you a promo code (because it is paid) of my app for you to check that out :). I didn't downgrade from armv7 to arm64 only so I can't give you that 100% but I am pretty sure it does work since I experienced some apps that I was able to download (iPhone 5) but later on I couldn't update since they required 64 bit. I don't know how to contact you privately (because of the promo code) could you give me your email or is there some better way? :) @EduardoCoelho

Comment: You might want to check my updated answer @EduardoCoelho