# iOS: limit app to 64-bit devices only

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9

According to the latest Apple WWDC, starting from ios 9 there should be a way to limit installing app only on 64 bit devices.

I searched in XCode for this option but could not find anything. Is this already possible and if yes, how can i enable it?

Comment: It's probably the CPU architecture settings (top of build settings)?

Comment: This will be helpful I suppose. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22878827/restricting-app-installations-from-appstore-only-to-users-with-iphone-5-5s-5c

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In Xcode, set the following values:

Build settings > Architectures

- Set to **arm64** only. (click Other -> + and than enter **arm64**)

Build settings > Valid architectures

- Set to **arm64** only.

Info.plist

- Set UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities to **arm64** only.

The app will then not be able to run on a device that does not support 64-bit code.

Comment: Thanks! Do i have to set deployment target to iOS 9 or can it stay 8.4?

Comment: No problem! 8.4 is fine.

Comment: You should also set `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` to arm64 in your Info.plist

Comment: You should also set the iOS Deployment Target to at least 8.0.

Comment: @Yuyo, have you tried a minimum of 7.0? The [iOS Support Matrix](http://dorianroy.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/iOS_Support_Matrix_v4.2.pdf) from the answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422447/what-iphone-devices-will-run-on-armv7s-and-arm64 suggests that would also work.

Comment: I ran ipa Validate after switching to arm64 only, and got an error like "arm64 in UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities requires iOS 8.0" and like "architectures 64-bit only requires iOS 8.0". So 8.0 or later for deployment target of arm64 only app should be enough, but 7.0 builds fine but will cause error when submitting an app.