# Can I convert my app for 64-bit with XCode 7.2.1?

Tags: ios

I want to update/convert my iOS App for 64-bit so it will still run on iOS 11. I am still on Yosemite and don't currently have the time to upgrade to El Capitan so I'm stuck with XCode 7.2.1. Is it even possible to convert my App to a 64-bit binary with that version of XCode?

If yes, does anyone know a good description of how to do this? I haven't coded in XCode for a while and don't know where to begin with this task.

Comment: 64-bit support was added way back in Xcode 5.

Answer (score 0):

[From here:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33646645/1166266)

In Xcode, set the following values:

Build settings > Architectures

- Set to **arm64** only. (click Other -> + and than enter **arm64**)

Build settings > Valid architectures

- Set to **arm64** only.

Really though I'd recommend you just update because you are missing out on a ton of features.

Comment: Is this within "Project" or "Target" or both?

Comment: @Sirens - In the future, instead of copying an existing answer, you should vote to close the question as a duplicate.

Comment: I have seen the other question and answer but didn't understand it enough. And it is quite old so I wasn't sure whether this is still true. So I'm glad about this answer.