# Developing new iOS apps for 64-bit architecture only

Tags: ios, iphone, 64-bit

Is it possible to submit 64-bit only app to the app store? I know starting Feb 1 2015, all new apps must include 64-bit support, but I'm wondering if a new app can be exclusively 64-bit?

EDIT: This would be <del>armv7s + arm64</del> arm64. I think armv7s is for iPhone 5, which is not 64-bit.

Comment: Here is something I found where someone asked a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30730411/800421  In short yes, you have to include armv7s

Comment: Thanks. I'm not good at UI design, so eliminating 3.5" screens should make things a little easier for me although iPhone 5 is 4", I believe.

Comment: I didn't want to deal with iphone 4 either.  But surprisingly a lot of people still use them so I would just do it even though it sucks.

Comment: Ugh. This is confusing. I also have min version 8.0. I think including armv7 automatically adds support for those older devices.

Comment: it does no way around it.  I think your are going to have to support the smaller sceens.  I don't know what your app is but if you are using size classes this should make it easier.  To support smaller screens i'm using size classes and changing the constraint constants based off of screen size.

Comment: Thanks. Although this is irrelevant to the original question, can I submit a new app as iPhone app only as opposed to universal?

Comment: Looks like iOS 9 is more flexible: http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/ios-9-developers-limit-support-old-devices/

Comment: Yes you can.  That is set in your app target under deployment info